# Check if process (URL) exists vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net

How would i just if a website exists, and, if so, launch a browser to open it. I am making a little tool for one of my freinds and it allow then to quickly launch websites. How would I check if that is a valid website to launch, so i don't get an error if it is not valid.

```
Private Sub btn4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn4.Click
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(web4)
        If cbxautoclose.Checked Then
            Me.Close()
        End If
    End Sub
```

The error i want to stop is "Cannot start process because a file name has not been provided."
So basically i want to make sure that the program can launch the URL so i don't get this error

Comment: By valid website you mean a valid URL? or that the web-site really exists (no 404 error)

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing. First I understood that you want to check whether the given URL exists, now you want to check whether the process is running. Could you be more specific which one of these is your question?

Comment: Just use a `Try` `Catch` block to catch the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thankyou Matt for the answer to this problem

```
try catch
```

was exactly what is needed

```
Try
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(web4)
            If cbxautoclose.Checked Then
                Me.Close()
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
```

Thankyou Matt

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are trying to check whether the url for a website is valid or not before launching the website through the tool. .Net framework has webclient class through which you can hit a url and see whether the website works or not.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Regex:

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"(https?|ftp|file)\://[A-Za-z0-9\.\-]+(/[A-Za-z0-9\?\&\=;\+!'\(\)\*\-\._~%]*)*");
If (r.Match("THE_URL").Success) Then
    /* The process will exist */
Else
  /* The process will not exist */
End If
```

Comment: Doesn't work :( is this translated from a different language to vb?

Comment: System.Text.RegularExpressions